# Count number of odd digits in Integer Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, int, integer

I'm trying to make program which counts the number of odd digits in integer using Haskell. I have ran into problem with checking longer integers. My program looks like this at the moment:

```
oddDigits:: Integer -> Int
x = 0
oddDigits i
   | i `elem` [1,3,5,7,9] = x + 1
   | otherwise = x + 0
```

If my integer is for example 22334455 my program should return value 4, because there are 4 odd digits in that integer. How can I check all numbers in that integer? Currently it only checks first digit and returns 1 or 0. I'm still pretty new to haskell.

Comment: You write this as an "imperative" program where you have a certain variable `x` that you aim to "update". Haskell does not have a "global" state.

Comment: `Integer`s don't have digits; string *representations* of integers do.

Answer (score 5):

You can first convert the integer `22334455` to a list `"22334455"`. Then find all the elements satisfying the requirement.

```
import Data.List(intersect)

oddDigits = length . (`intersect` "13579") . show
```

Comment: If I use function from other answer which turns integer to list, how do I use it with this? Can I do something like this: `oddDigits s = length. (´intersect´ digits' s) . show`

Comment: you would write it like this: `oddDigits = length . (`intersect` [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]) . digits'

Comment: @JonH it seems you're confused about the type of a list.  if `22334455 `is an integer then `show 22334455` is `[Char]`; if `22334455 `is an integer then `digits' 22334455` is  `[Integer]`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to solve such problems, you typically split this up into smaller problems. A typical pipeline would be:

1. split the number in a list of digits;
2. filter the digits that are odd; and
3. count the length of the resulting list.

You thus can here implement/use helper functions. For example we can generate a list of digits with:

```
digits' :: Integral i => i -> [i]
digits' 0 = []
digits' n = r : digits' q
    where (q, r) = quotRem n 10
```

Here the digits will be produced in *reverse* order, but since that does not influences the number of digits, that is not a problem. I leave the other helper functions as an exercise.

Comment: I have problems to use this function to check list for odds.How can I get list made in this function to work on the other?

Comment: @JonH: take a look at `filter`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter

Comment: You're suggesting to produce a list that will be immediately consumed, but that list fusion won't be able to work on. While this is probably fine for this narrow use-case since most numbers don't have very many digits, isn't that a bad practice in general?

Comment: I find more issues with premature optimizations than with lists not fusing.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson is it really premature optimization when `unfoldr` is sitting right there?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an efficient way to do that:

```
oddDigits :: Integer -> Int
oddDigits = go 0
  where
    go :: Int -> Integer -> Int
    go s 0 = s
    go s n = s `seq` go (s + fromInteger r `mod` 2) q
      where (q, r) = n `quotRem` 10
```

This is tail-recursive, doesn't accumulate thunks, and doesn't build unnecessary lists or other structures that will need to be garbage collected. It also handles negative numbers correctly.